# Create a Code Block in Google Doc via PHP client

Tags: google-workspace, google-docs-api

Google Doc UI has a capability under Insert menu -> Building block -> Code block to insert a code block. I was wondering how can this code block be added programmatically via API or through programming clients such as PHP, Python, etc. to the google doc?

Comment: Rummaging through the Google Docs API Library for [Python](https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/dyn/docs_v1.documents.html#create) and [PHP](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/docs/v1/php/latest/class-Google_Service_Docs_EmbeddedObject.html) and it seems that adding a code block format unto a Google Document is not yet possible. You can submit a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=555502&template=1211190) instead.